# Why cant i access window.variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, scope

I am declaring windows.uris outside any function,
then i'm adding elements in $.each(), at the last line when alerting window.uris is empty.
Why ?

```
window.uris = new Array(); 

window.groups = new Array();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


host = document.location.host,
path = document.location.pathname;
url = host + path;
var domg = new Object();
var optgroup;
var productsDom = "";

  if (contains(url, 'manage/items.php')) {
    $.post('http://localhost/frontaccounting/proxy.php',
    {
        "url":"http://localhost:8081/stock/categories/",
        "m":"get",
        "data": ""
    },
      function (data) {
        d = $.parseXML(data);
        $xml = $( d );

        $xml.find("category").each(
            function (i,e) {
                optgroup = '<optgroup label="'+ $(e).children("name").text()+'">';
                categoryId = $(e).children("id").text();
                auxx =  (categoryId*1);
                window.uris[i]="http://localhost:8081/stock/categories/" + (auxx );
                window.groups[auxx + ""] = optgroup;
            }
        );
    }
    );  
    //sleep(2000);
        alert('URI' + window.uris);
```

Comment: you should do the alert inside the post callbac, here it get called before window.uris is feed

Comment: Your ajax is asynchronous. If you put another alert inside the `$.post` callback, you'll notice that it is alerted *after* the current one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function you make an *asynchronous* call to some url. The `alert` command, however, is inside your function and *not* inside the callback.

So it will be called immediatly instead of waiting until the AJAX-request has finished and your data is present.

A simple solution is to move your `alert` inside the callback-function.

Comment: I implemented a sleep function function sleep(ms)
 {
  var dt = new Date();
  dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + ms);
  while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
 }  . And it does not matter how much i wait before the alert() at the end

Comment: @Blitzkr1eg A sleep function at that point is far from optimal. What happens, if your request takes a little longer for whatever reason? Put your further logic inside the callback function or call another function from there to make sure the request is actually completed, before using the data!